# Is "condition for noun verb ing" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

For example, should I say:

There are two conditions for the box containing a ball.

or

There are two conditions for the box's containing a ball. ?

The second one seems more correct, but I know for sure the following is correct, where there is no "'s"

There are three boxes on the table with the blue one containing a ball.

Is this because of the special usage of "with?"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that there are two conditions that must be met for the box to contain a ball?

Comment: Yes, I basically mean that. Imagine the context is like this:   <br/><br/>     There are two conditions for the box containing a ball. One is that the box is bigger than the ball. The other is that there is room in the box.

<br/><br/>    But my main question is whether there should be 's after the word "for" (and why there is no 's after "with" in the other example) ...

Answer (score 2):

No, you would not say it either of those two ways you proposed in English. You would use an infinitive clause not a gerund clause.

> There are two conditions **for the box to contain a ball**.

The versions with the gerunds don’t sound natural to me. You could also put it this way:

> For the box to contain a ball, two conditions must be met.

Comment: Thanks!  I learned the the two ways here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/necessary-sufficient/        <br/>   If you search that webpage for "condition for", then you see both ways appear in the 19 results.  <br/><br/>  I am not sure if the article is written by an English speaker.